# Possible to use ?? (the coalesce operator) with DBNull?

Tags: c#, .net, null-coalescing-operator

If I have code similar to the following:

```
while(myDataReader.Read())
{
  myObject.intVal = Convert.ToInt32(myDataReader["mycolumn"] ?? 0);
}
```

It throws the error:

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

defining `intVal` as a nullable int is not an option.  Is there a way for me to do the above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling DBNull in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433155/handle-dbnull-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you use an extension method?   (written off the top of my head)

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions 
{
    public static T Read<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string column, T defaultValue = default(T))
    {
        var value = reader[column];

        return (T)((DBNull.Value.Equals(value))
                   ? defaultValue
                   : Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T)));
    }
}
```

You'd use it like:

```
while(myDataReader.Read())
{
  int i = myDataReader.Read<int>("mycolumn", 0);
}
```

Comment: I ended up going the extension method route.  I was getting an error with the `Convert.ChangeType...` portion so I made some minor changes.

Comment: Can you update my answer with the 'minor changes' you had to make?

Comment: Actually I'm still having some trouble getting the casting to work.  `Convert.ChangeType (reader[column], typeof(T))` does not compile, so I switched to this `(T)reader[column]` which throws a runtime exception.  Any ideas?

Comment: That did it, thanks for the followup.  Ended up rolling back my minor changes

Answer (score 22):

Here's one more option:

```
while (myDataReader.Read())
{
    myObject.intVal = (myDataReader["mycolumn"] as int? ?? 0);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely best way! Thanks Edyn.

Comment: Brilliant answer! So clean.

Answer (score 7):

Can you simply use `Int32.Tryparse`?

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(myDataReader["mycolumn"].ToString(), out number);
```

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx), `number` will contain 0 if the conversion failed

Comment: +1, good answer.  This would have worked but the int I am actually trying to assign to is an object property which does not work with `out`.

Comment: This doesn't compile, does it?  The data reader indexer returns an object reference, TryParse takes a string parameter.  Of course, you could call `ToString` on the object, but it's rather inefficient to construct the string representation of an int just so you can parse it.  An unboxing conversion would be much more efficent.

Comment: @phoog, good point.  If it's null ToString would bomb anyway.  Could use `as string` instead.

Comment: @AbeMiessler `as string` would return null if the object is a boxed int, raising an exception in `TryParse`. But the DataReader's indexer is guaranteed not to return `null`; null data values are represented by `DBNull.Value` (which takes us back to where we started!). So the logic is sound if you call `.ToString()`; it's just inefficient.

Comment: I've added the .ToString() to make the answer compile. I certainly admit this is not an efficient solution, but thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 5):

How about something like:

```
object x = DBNull.Value;
int y = (x as Int32?).GetValueOrDefault(); //This will be 0
```

Or in your case:

```
int i = (myDataReader["mycolumn"] as Int32?).GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: As John Saunders pointed out in his answer to the linked "possible duplicate" question, this approach has the disadvantage of failing to raise an exception if the data type of the column changes. For example, if "mycolumn" holds a `short` value of 42, the variable `i` will have a value of `0`. A direct cast would raise an exception, calling attention to the type mismatch between the code and the database.

Comment: @phoog - Valid point, I guess every method has its pros and cons.  Personally, I like my DB and code as tightly coupled as I can.  I'd either use an `int?` in code, or not allow `null` in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use something other than the null coalescing operator (`DBNull.Value` != `null`):

```
int i = myDataReader["mycolumn"] == DBNull.Value ?
            Convert.ToInt32(myDataReader["mycolumn"]) :
            0;
```

You could always wrap it up in a neat extension method:

```
public static T Read<T>(this DataReader reader, string column, T defaultVal)
{
    if(reader[column] == DBNull.Value) return defaultVal;
    return Convert.ChangeType(reader[column], typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: I considered a ternary if but `??` seems cleaner if I can pull it off.

Comment: @AbeMiessler I don't think `??` will work with `DBNull`; it's not actually `null`.

Comment: You got it the other way round. Also I would suggest this method is not that efficient.

Comment: Did you just dump in my extension method posted above?

Comment: @insta - Nope. Just realized an extension method would be nice to have. Only so many ways to write that code though (and after looking, the code doesn't even match).

Comment: @JustinNiessner: I'm not upset it was just kinda confusing to see the same method name and parameters and at-a-glance the same code :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, only works for nulls.

How about an extension method on object that checks for DBNull, and returns a default value instead?

```
//may not compile or be syntactically correct! Just the general idea.
public static object DefaultIfDBNull( this object TheObject, object DefaultValue )
{
    if( TheObject is DBNull )
        return DefaultValue;
    return TheObject;
}
```

Comment: Why not use generics rather than `object`?

Comment: @dlev In the context of dealing with the non generic datareader I thought this would be easier. It was just off the top of my head. The generic answer from insta looks pretty good.