# should I use isDbNull? How to use it in this particular case?

Tags: c#, mysql

I know `Null` values can't be turned into string values so I looked all over the web and did find some answers like using `IsDBNull()` but I can't seem to get it working. I'm new at this so please bear with me. I simply need the nullable field to be populated in the proper `TextBox` as `""` when it's `Null`. If you could give me a hand with the proper syntax it would be great. the field that may be `Null` (or not) is `projects_project_number`, I went back to my original code to show what I started with. Here it is:

```
ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
string Query = "select * from shopmanager.quotes where idquotes = @search_quote_number;";

MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
MySqlDataReader myReader;
try
{
    con.Open();

    cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search_quote_number", search_quote_number.Text);
    myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        string sClient_number = myReader.GetString("client_info_client_number");
        string sId = myReader.GetInt16("idquotes").ToString();
        string sClientName = myReader.GetString("client_name");
        string spredicted_start_date = myReader.GetString("predicted_start_date");
        string sdate_required = myReader.GetString("requested_date");
        string sdate_predicted = myReader.GetString("delivery_expected_date");
        string sdate_received = myReader.GetString("date_received");
        string squote_amount = myReader.GetString("quote_amount");
        string sproject_number = myReader.GetString("projects_project_number");

        quote_id.Text = sId;
        client_name.Text = sClientName;
        predicted_start_date.Text = spredicted_start_date;
        date_required.Text = sdate_required;
        date_predicted.Text = sdate_predicted;
        date_received.Text = sdate_received;
        quote_amount.Text = squote_amount;
        project_number.Text = sproject_number;

        temp_client_id.client_id = sClient_number;
        search_quote_number.Text = "";
    }
    cmdDataBase.Parameters.Clear();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: I cant see where DbNull is used at all.  Tip: you dont have to store data into a string var before posting it to a control.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Could you share an example? Projet_project_number is the field that can be null

Comment: `if (!myReader.IsDbNull(3)) txtBoxForTheName.Text = myReader.GetString("Name");`  Where `3` is the index for that field. Saving dates as strings as appears to be the case is a bad idea

Comment: I'd recommend looking into micro ORMs (like PetaPoco or Dapper) to avoid you having to worry about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the [DBNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=netframework-4.7.2) follow the guidance on MSDN about [Is.DBNull()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.isdbnull?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_IsDBNull_System_Object_)

There is multiple ways to use the `DBNull` but using what you have gave in your question, the best use would be:

```
string sproject_number = string.Empty;

if (!Convert.IsDBNull(myReader.GetString("projects_project_number"))) //check if value is not null
        sproject_number = myReader.GetString("projects_project_number"); 

project_number.Text = sproject_number;
```

You can also use the built in function for the `SqlDataReader` `.IsDBNull`:

```
int columnIndex = myReader.GetOrdinal("projects_project_number"); //get column index
string sproject_number = string.Empty;

if (!myReader.IsDBNull(columnIndex)) //check if value is not null
        sproject_number = myReader[columnIndex].ToString(); 

project_number.Text = sproject_number;
```

and for completeness:

```
int columnIndex = myReader.GetOrdinal();
string sproject_number = string.Empty;

if (DBNull.Value.Equals(myReader.GetString("projects_project_number"))) //check if value is not null
        sproject_number = myReader.GetString("projects_project_number");

project_number.Text = sproject_number;
```

Evaluating on a comment on original post about assigning to the textboxes directly and tidying everything up (and adding it into a `using` block is good practice):

```
ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"]
string Query = "select * from shopmanager.quotes where idquotes = @search_quote_number;";
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString()))
{
  using(MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, con))
  {
    cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search_quote_number", search_quote_number.Text.Trim());
    con.Open();
    var myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

    if(myReader.Read())
    {
      temp_client_id.client_id = myReader.GetString("client_info_client_number");
      quote_id.Text = myReader.GetInt16("idquotes").ToString();
      client_name.Text = myReader.GetString("client_name");
      predicted_start_date.Text = myReader.GetString("predicted_start_date");
      date_required.Text = sdate_required = myReader.GetString("requested_date");
      date_predicted.Tex = myReader.GetString("delivery_expected_date");
      date_received.Text = myReader.GetString("date_received");
      quote_amount.Text = myReader.GetString("quote_amount");
      project_number.Text = DBNull.Value.Equals(myReader.GetString("projects_project_number")) ? "" : myReader.GetString("projects_project_number");

      search_quote_number.Text = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The DbDataReader has an IsDbNull method built in

Comment: Yeah there is more than one way to skin a cat, I am just going with what he has gave me because we are using `SqlDataReader.GetString(string)` and the use of `SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(int)` would require some more changes to OP's code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
string sproject_number = DBNull.Value.Equals(myReader.GetString("projects_project_number")) ? "" : myReader.GetString("projects_project_number");
```

Or you can use an extension method like in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436852/possible-to-use-the-coalesce-operator-with-dbnull):