# Checking null and enforce to 0

Tags: c#, ado.net, null

I am returning an integer list from a datacolumn. This particular column is (int,null).
But I got an exception.

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

Code:

```
public List <int> GetSortOrder(DataTable dt,string columnName)
{
    List<int> Orders = new List<int>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Orders.Add((int)row[columnName]);
    }
    return Orders;
}
```

What I want is if it is null, then forcing it as 0.
Should I use nullable type int? or just simply using if ... else...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column actually stores DBNull.Value instead of usual C# null. That's why operator ?? is not working. To check if the column is null use row.IsNull method:

```
Orders.Add(row.IsNull(columnName) ? 0 : (int)row[columnName]);
```

Operator ?? doesn't work with DBNulls.

You may also want to check this link: [Handle DBNull in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433155/handle-dbnull-in-c-sharp) for some efficient examples of converting DBNull-able int to int?

Answer (score 6):

```
        Orders.Add((int)(row[columnName] ?? 0));
```

Comment: it's called the 'null coalescing operator'

Comment: If I use .Net 3.5, can I use ??

Comment: @Skeet Does ?? operator work with DBNull.Value? DataRow usually stores DBNull.Value but not null. I have tested DBNull.Value ?? 0 and got DBNull.Value.

Answer (score 1):

I would also use an int?  I like the Field method:

```
int? myInt = row.Field<int?>(columnName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest `int?`:

```
Orders.Add(((int?)row[columnName]).GetValueOrDefault());
```

In my opinion, it keeps the intent and code clear and concise, which an `if`/`else` doesn't do quite as well.  Using `?? 0` as the other answers have suggested is also good.

Comment: The intent of the code is to return an integer that is defaulted to 0, according to the original question.  I don't see how allowing a `null` value in the list improves clariry or intent - it would seem to contradict both.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
public List <int> GetSortOrder(DataTable dt,string columnName)
{
    List<int> Orders = new List<int>();
    int? nullableInt;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        nullableInt = (int)row[columnName];
        Orders.Add(nullableInt??0);
    }
    return Orders;
}
```

Comment: No, you'll still get an error when you try to cast a `null` value to `int`.  You need to cast to `int?`.

Comment: I wasn't sure as I didn't actually try it with real data. But it does compile like that...

Comment: Of course it compiles, because row[columnName] is of type object. The exception is thrown at runtime. By the way both (int)row[columnName] and (int?)row[columnName] throw an exception when row[columnName] is DBNull.Value.