# How to handle all DBNulls without checking for them every time (with a generated DataSet)?

Tags: c#, .net, dbnull

My original question was, as @nicholas correctly pointed, a little misleading, because this case is a little specific.

So here's the real problem:

I created Windows Form Application with DataGridView control and a DataSource generated from a table in my production database.

The goal of my program is to view the table, optionally edit comment columns and to export the table data to a XML file, which schema is strictly defined both with XSD and other independent constraints I cannot change.

It is especially important that I must not insert some fields into my XML output file if some values are not defined.

It's explicitly said I must not insert empty tags for those fields. That's the reason I need null values. To insert XML tags only where the value is given. That's why I need DBNull values, not any other default values.

The generated DataSet contains getters which throw an exception on accessing DBNull values. I cannot change generated code, it's a rule, you don't change generated code, especially the code which could (and would) be overwritten.

I solved this problem by surrounding each assignment of a nullable field with a "try/catch" block. If the generated getter throws an exception, my nullable field of my XML object will keep it's default null value, which is my expected behavior.

Later - my XML constructor will skip those fields while generating XML output.

But one problem remains: why does it have to be so ugly? What if I had a hundred nullable fields? Would I have to write a hundred "try/catch" blocks? It seems like a bug in the whole Microsoft mechanism to me. Or maybe there's a simple and elegant solution to this?

--
Here's the original content, to understand where the first answers came from:

> Please, I do know I could check each field for DBNull, but there must
>   be a automatic way for programmers. It would be the most stupid thing
>   in whole .NET/C# - having to write "if" or "try/catch" statement for
>   each column of my huge table! I've tried to use "foreach" on my table
>   row type, but it didn't work. The exceptions are thrown at the very
>   beginning of "foreach" body, it seems if I even try to touch DBNull,
>   the exception is thrown. If I put my whole code block inside
>   "try/catch" - it won't work because it will skip all fields behind
>   first DBNull.
>
> There must be a way to do it without putting a couple of dozens fugly
>   checks in my code. So, what is the magic trick for the rows with
>   DBNulls?

Comment: Write a function to extract the value, or a default value if DBNull, and use it when you need to read a column

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3050744/1106367) might help.

Comment: One line of code; see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433155/handle-dbnull-in-c-sharp

Comment: I forgot to mention: there is a generated getter which throws the exception - there's no way to touch DBNull value. And there's no way to change that getter - of course I can change it (for every NULL column) but it will be overwritten with each change to related objects. Dear Microsoft, why did you do such thing? I thought NULL is a normal value in TSQL, not the "always throwing a stupid pointless exception" one. I don't need a default value!

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this IDataRecord @this, string name, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    int ordinal = @this.GetOrdinal(name));
    return @this.GetValue<T>(ordinal, defaultValue);
} 

public static T GetValue<T>(this IDataRecord @this, int ordinal, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    return @this.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? defaultValue : (T)@this.GetValue(ordinal);
}
```

Use it like so:

```
connstr = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Test;";

string sql = "select WidgetId, WidgetName, WidgetValue, CreatedDt, ModifiedDt from dbo.widgets";

using (connection = new SqlConnection(connstr))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.Write(reader.GetValue<int>("WidgetId").ToString());
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(reader.GetValue<string>("WidgetName"));
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(reader.GetValue<int>("WidgetValue"));
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(reader.GetValue<DateTime>("CreatedDt"));
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(reader.GetValue<DateTime>("ModifiedDt"));
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
1       Widget 1        0       7/17/2012 6:13:26 AM    1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
2       Widget 2        0       7/17/2012 6:13:26 AM    1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
3       Widget 3        0       7/17/2012 6:13:26 AM    1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the DbNull values prior to retrieving them from the server by modifying your SQL select query to call `IsNull` (or in the case of an Access back-end `Nz`). [Definition here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp).

```
string sql = "select WidgetId, IsNull(WidgetName,""), " +
             "IsNull(WidgetValue,0), CreatedDt, ModifiedDt from dbo.widgets";
```

Assuming you have some kind of appropriate default value or use a sentinel value for catching the nulls later on.

Comment: I need null values. Null means I don't put a tag into output XML, "" and 0 and similar mean I need to put an empty tag or tag with "0" content. The XML schema and rules are not defined by me, so I would have to make a very dirty workaround for this. Nulls are just necessary for the whole thing to work.

Comment: @Harry, I'd recommend revising your original question to reflect these additional constraints / desired results of your program (including your comment on the 'generated getter')

Comment: you're definitely right. I think my question is a little bit misleading.